# Android Activity keeps crashing no idea why

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following activity code but when I run the app it crashes immidiately and I have no idea why. The code seems good. Wny tips?

That's the partial code of the manifest file

Manifest:

```
<activity 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".level1Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

My activity's class code

level1Activity.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Level1Activity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
       //rest of the code
   }
}
```

And last my layout xml code.

activity_level1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mainbgcolor"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/level1_welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/level1_step1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/level1_step1_det"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/level1_intro1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What you are getting in logcat?

Comment: please post logcat output

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml you  declared **android:name=".level1Activity"** and your Activity class is  **Level1Activity** . Change .level1Activity to .Level1Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your android:name=".level1Activity" and your class is not same so it crashes.